# How to turn column header into pandas index

Tags: python, pandas, database, reshape

So my pandas df currently looks something like this:

| Detail | Person 1 | Person 2 | Person 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Steve | Larry | Dave |
| Age | 45 | 56 | 67 |
| Hobbie | Running | Skating | Painting |

But I want to reshape it to this:

| Person | Name | Age | Hobbie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Person 1 | Steve | 45 | Running |
| Person 2 | Larry | 56 | Skating |
| Person 3 | Dave | 67 | Painting |

Anyone know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
out = (df.set_index('Detail').T
         .rename_axis('Person')
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
     Person   Name Age    Hobbie
0  Person 1  Steve  45   Running
1  Person 2  Larry  56   Skating
2  Person 3   Dave  67  Painting
```

Comment: Worked! Cheers for the help

Comment: What is the T for?

Comment: To transpose the columns and rows

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is transpose the dataframe with `df.T` and rename the column name using `df.rename()`. But there is a catch while using `df.T` it also transpose the index column to row. So we need to work around it.
Here is the step by step code:

data.csv:

```
Detail,Person 1,Person 2,Person 3
Name,Steve,Larry,Dave
Age,45,56,67
Hobbie,Running,Skating,Painting
```

Reading from file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(df)
```

output:

```
   Detail Person 1 Person 2  Person 3
0    Name    Steve    Larry      Dave
1     Age       45       56        67
2  Hobbie  Running  Skating  Painting
```

Changing the column name:

```
df = df.rename(columns={"Detail":"Person"})
print(df)
```

output:

```
   Person Person 1 Person 2  Person 3
0    Name    Steve    Larry      Dave
1     Age       45       56        67
2  Hobbie  Running  Skating  Painting
```

Transposing with new index column:

```
df = df.set_index('Person').T
print(df)
```

output:

```
Person     Name Age    Hobbie
Person 1  Steve  45   Running
Person 2  Larry  56   Skating
Person 3   Dave  67  Painting
```